# Nginx daemon stop is failing

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, daemon, init.d

I've got Ubuntu 11.04 i386 server with nginx 1.0.11 installed. Also, I'm using [this init.d script](https://github.com/JasonGiedymin/nginx-init-ubuntu), the only one I've found in several different places. It starts the server nicely, however, on stop/reset it says

```
* Stopping Nginx Server...      [fail]
```

Of course, the daemon is not stopped, and upon restart the configuration is not reloaded.

How can I repair this?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It's likely that it can't kill the process.

Open up the nginx sysvinit script located in /etc/init.d/ (or /etc/rc.d/) and find where nginx.pid is thought to be. It'll be something like "/var/run/nginx.pid".

If the pid file isn't there, open nginx.conf and look for the pid setting. If it is a mismatch - set the conf value to where the script thinks it should be, e.g.

```
# pid of nginx process
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;
```

Comment: for me, it was `/run/nginx.pid` in nginx.conf that i replaced with `/var/run/nginx.pid` and it worked. thanks!

Comment: Thanks - I was seeing the pid file in both dirs, but changing the init and nginx.conf to point to the 'var' dir instead solved the same problem on my stop/restart script.

Answer (score 15):

`sudo service nginx restart`  will give you something like this:

```
Stopping nginx:                                            [FAILED]
Starting nginx: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] still could not bind()
```

then kill the process manually by their port:

`sudo fuser -k 80/tcp`  (or use whatever port you are using)

alternatively, kill the processes by their ID:

```
ps -ef |grep nginx
kill <pid>
```

Answer (score 3):

try this command:

```
sudo fuser -k 80/tcp
```

Answer (score 2):

### Cause of this issue

- When you start nginx, it writes the pid to the file defined in `nginx.conf`

  - Refer: http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#pid
- When you run `service nginx stop`, it stops the process whose PID is defined according to `/usr/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service` (your path may be different)

  - This means that the process is not actually stopped.
- When you try to start it again, it tries to bind to the same port and throws an error.

Basically, you are writing the PID at location A and trying to read it from location B. This inconsistency seems to be the root cause of this apparently common issue.

### Solution

#### Proper fix:

We need to ensure that both the read and write locations are same.

**How?**: 
The pid file defined in `nginx.conf` and `nginx.service` should be the same.

#### Hotfix:

1. `lsof -i | grep nginx`

This will give you the pid. In my case, there were two of them.

2. `kill -9 pid1`
3. `kill -9 pid2` (may not be required)

Answer (score 1):

I had faced similar issues.

Generally I use apache/apache2.

The following might help you:

```
sudo nginx -s stop | ps -ef | grep nginx | awk {'print $2'} | xargs sudo kill -9 | sudo service apache2 start
```

For docs please refer this [Github Gist](https://gist.github.com/nrshrivatsan/4a1c288801a00e173bd9)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an nginx init script that I modified (based on the outdated [offical init script](http://wiki.nginx.org/Nginx-init-ubuntu)) that works with many debian-based distros, including Ubuntu 11.04:

https://github.com/hulihanapplications/nginx-init-debian

This works pretty well on my ubuntu servers. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an nginx init script that I modified (based on the official init script), I make the script's variable

```
lockfile=$pidfile
```

and the variable

```
pidfile="/var/run/nginx.pid"
```

Then I modified the config file (`nginx.conf`), I make the variable

```
pid="/var/run/nginx.pid"
```

too.

Finally I can use all the nginx commands normally.